# Activity Indicator doesn't spin

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to add a spinning activity indicator (UIActivityIndicatorView) to my app while it parses data from the internet. I have an IBOutlet (spinner) connected to a UIActivityIndicatorView in IB. Initially I had it set up like this:

```
-

 (void) function {
        self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
 self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
 [spinner startAnimating];
 //parse data from internet
 [spinner stopAnimating];}
```

But the spinner wouldn't spin. I read that it had something to do with everything being on the same thread. So I tried this:

```
    - (void) newFunction {
        self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
 self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
 [spinner startAnimating];
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(function) toTarget: self withObject: nil];
 [spinner stopAnimating];}
```

But still no luck. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Your `newFunction:` method should look like this:

```
- (void) newFunction {
   self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
   self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(function) toTarget: self withObject: nil];
}
```

And your `function` method should look like this:

```
- (void) function {
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   [self.spinner performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

   //...

   [self.spinner performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
   [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer, with the addendum that the reason why he's not seeing anything is because he stops the animation immediately after it starts on the main thread. The reason he has to `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` is because all UI related activity happens on the main thread, but the starting/stopping of the spinner must occur from within the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

you should not intitialize indicator again .please replace your code with this.

```
-(void) function {
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [self performSelector:@selector(newfunction) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
}
- (void) newfunction {
     [spinner stopAnimating];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just see that the "//parse data from internet " is synchronous or asynchronous. Asynchronous would mean that a separate thread would start from that point on, and the current function execution will continue without delay.

In your second example, you are explicitly making separate thread, which means that `@selector(function)` will happen on a separate thread, and the next statement `[spinner stopAnimating]` is executed immediately. So, it seems like spinner is not spinning at all.

Moreover, make sure you start and stop the activity indicator on main thread only.